# JScrollPane drawing components under itself

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane inside of a JTabbedPane tab.  Into that JScrollPane I place a JPanel whose background is red and whose size is explicitly set.

This is what I get:

[image]

[image]

Note that in the second image, where the container frame has been resized, the component is *being drawn under the scrollbar elements*.

What's going on here?  I've tried just about every combination of layout managers for all the components involved (as well as components besides JPanel - ultimately I want several JEditorPane here), and I cannot get anything to draw except under a big, blank, rectangle (is it a background?  which?)

Code:

In main JFrame subclass:

```
// Called once on startup/layout.
public void refreshGUIState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < client.getFrameStackLength(); i++) {
        InferenceFrame frame = client.getFrame(i);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                                           JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        JPanel wtf = new JPanel();
        pane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        wtf.setBackground(Color.red);
        wtf.setSize(100,100);
        wtf.setPreferredSize(wtf.getSize());
        pane.add(wtf);
        workspace.addTab(Integer.toString(i), pane);
    }
}

public GuiClient() throws CliException, ParticleSourceException {
    super("L4 Interactive Prover");
    setSize(800,600);

    mainArea = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true);
    mainArea.setDividerSize(2);
    mainArea.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    getContentPane().add(mainArea);

    /* ... menu bar init ... */

    toolspace = new JPanel();
    workspace = new JTabbedPane();
    mainArea.add(toolspace);
    mainArea.add(workspace);

    this.validate();
    refreshGUIState();
}
```

Edit: under the suspicion that JScrollPane was somehow not creating a viewport when its first child was added, as expected, I also tried the three-argument constructor.   Same behavior.

Re-edit:   Except I erred and left in the add() call.  Whoops.  Looks like that's it.

Comment: My guess is that you forgot to add the thing to the scroll pane.

Comment: I do that on the line that reads "pane.add(wtf);".   The code is right there...   And you can see it drawn in the image, it's just under a rectangle of gray.  So..... .

Comment: Where are you setting the frame visible?

Comment: In the main().   Obviously the frame is visible, or you would not see it in the screenshots.  All main() does is create new instance, set the default close operation, and setVisible().

Comment: I'm pretty sure that instead of `pane.add(wtf)` you need `pane.setViewportView(wtf)`. Or, you can do it while initialising the JScrollPane: `new JScrollPane(wtf)`.

Comment: Salvatore Ella - See my edits above.   I expected the first child add() to automatically have a viewport created. Looks like that's it.   Go ahead and make it an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
pane.add(wtf);
```

you need

```
pane.setViewportView(wtf);
```

You can also do it when initialising the JScrollPane:

```
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(wtf);
```

Or, in your case:

```
JScollPane pane = new JScrollPane(wtf, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```